# How to use streamlinejs in expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express

When I use expressjs, but I don't know how to use it with [streamlinejs](https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs).

Look at the express code:

```
var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
   User.find({name:'Jack'}, function(err, users) {
      res.send(users);
   });
});
```

How to use streamlinejs in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a point I'm covering quickly in the FAQ (https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs/blob/master/FAQ.md#the-underscore-trick-is-designed-for-callbacks-but-not-events-how-do-i-deal-with-events).

The easiest solution is to add the underscore as extra parameter to the `get` callback:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res, next, _) {
   var users = User.find({name:'Jack'}, _);
   res.send(users);
});
```

The only problem would be if `connect` adds a fourth parameter to its callback some day. The following is a bit safer (but probably overkill because I don't see why `connect` would change its callback API):

```
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
   (function(_) {
      var users = User.find({name:'Jack'}, _);
      res.send(users);
   })(trap); // trap is a generic callback that handles errors
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, it does have the third parameter. See the demo in expressjs document: `app.get('/users/:id?', function(req, res, next){..}`

Comment: Then you can add the underscore as fourth parameter `function(req, res, next, _) {..}`, or use the second solution.

Comment: I edited the answer to add the `next` parameter. I also added the `trap` parameter in the second solution.

Comment: I don't know if either of you guys have tested this already or not, but adding a fourth parameter may make Express think that the route is an error-handling route. Last I checked, it looks at the handler's `length` to determine that. I would thus avoid that.

Comment: Where do I found the `trap`? I just use it, but reports: `trap is not defined`

Comment: `trap` is a function that you would write. For example: `function trap(err) { console.error(err); }`

Answer (score 1):

We use Express and Streamline for [The Thingdom](http://www.thethingdom.com/), and to do that, we built a simple wrapper that allows the `next` callback (third parameter) to be a Streamline-friendly callback, for both route handlers and middleware handlers.

Here you go:

https://gist.github.com/1087991

=)

<del>I've been meaning to make that into a generic module and publish to npm -- I'll do that soon.</del> **Edit: https://github.com/aseemk/express-streamline**

Note that there is one trade-off as a result of this -- you can't have route handlers "continue" (fall through) to other route handlers. We've never used that feature, though, and don't foresee ourselves doing so -- it's much simpler to know that every route handler is the final destination -- so we were okay with that trade-off.

**Edit:** This is only tested with Express 2.x.